# Single robots.txt file for all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, robots.txt

I have a site (example.com) and have my robots.txt set up in the root directory. I have also multiple subdomains (foo.example.com, bar.example.com, and more to come in the future) whose robots.txt will all be identical as that of example.com. I know that I can place a file at the root of each subdomain but I'm wondering if it's possible to redirect the crawlers searching for robots.txt on any subdomain to example.com/robots.txt?

Comment: Yes, you can. Or you can symlink it. Whichever you find easier.

Comment: @Wrikken Can I add a `RedirectMatch` to the root's .htaccess to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a redirect header for your robots.txt file is not advised, nor is it officially supported.

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) specifically states:

> Handling of robots.txt redirects to disallowed URLs is undefined and discouraged.

But the documentation does say redirect "will be *generally* followed". If you add your subdomains into Google Webmaster Tools and go to "Crawl > Blocked URLs" you can test your subdomain robots.txts that are 301 redirecting. It should come back as positively working.

However, with that said, I would *strongly* suggest that you just symlink the files into place and that each robots.txt file responds with a 200 OK at the appropriate URLs. This is much more inline with the original robots.txt specification, as well as, Google's documentation, and who knows exactly how bing / yahoo will handle it over time.